# изменить текст на кнопке

Tags: javascript

Ребят подскажите, нужно при отправке данных, пока форма грузиться , отключить кнопку, инпут файл и изменить текст на кнопке.
форма:

```js
function zapret() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = true;

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form_add text-center" onsubmit="zapret()" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <input id="myFile" name="myFile" type="file" accept=".zip,.rar" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

пока только навоял что кнопка отключается, остальное не получается.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="this.disabled=1;  this.textContent='Отправка...'; ">Отправить</button>
```

Comment: Вы задание читали? Нужно текст и disabled изменить на время отправки формы, т.е. как я понял на время обработки Ajax.

Comment: Тогда в самой функции, которая выполняет ajax, вначале устанавливаете на кнопке нужные надписи и отключаете ее, а потом, в секции success меняете обратно или на те значения, что вам нужны.

Comment: @MadFox а вы задание читали? В вопросе форма, и она не отправляет данные с помощью ajax при submit, а перегружает страницу. Поэтому ответ вполне имеет место быть.

Comment: Парни форма переходит на другую страницу, но пока грузиться (так как отправляються файлы) - нужно отключить загрузку файлов и кнпку отправки + изменить в ней текст - что бы люди не клацали пока ждут загрузку файлов

Comment: Исходя из вашей задачи (форма переходит на другую страницу, а вам надо лишь дисаблить и изменять надпись кнопки на время загрузки), решение повесить код на кнопку очень даже адекватное. Но если пользователь остается на странице и после загрузки надо все вернуть назад, тогда в ajax надо дописать секцию  success:, которая выполняется после получения ответа с сервера. Опять таки, надо знать какой именно ответ приходит. Выложите код ajax функции.